# How do I capture the image of a person when he blinks his eye in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to create and camera app that will capture the photo when he blinks his eyes or any movement happened using flutter, how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recognise Object & Scene Recognition . For this You can Use Wikitude SDK :

The Wikitude Flutter Component enables Dart developers to embed an augmented reality view into their Flutter project. One can create a fully featured app with advanced augmented reality features, including GEO AR, image and object tracking and Wikitude SMART (Seamless AR Tracking) for markerless tracking.

https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/flutter/objecttracking.html

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Does it help me to automatically capture the image also?